# Another way to say: "Evidences that show that..."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I need to write something similar to this:

> Evidences that show that this method is both safe and provides
>   clinical benefits support its recommendation.

I would like to say it without using "show". I had "Evidence **of that** this method...." written, but I think that it's incorrect.

Which would be the correct way to say that?

Comment: Evidence is a non-count (or mass) noun so shouldn't be pluralized.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Writing advice is on topic at Writers.SE. Thank you.

Comment: @Mitch, as you can see at the link in my accepted answer, your comment is an oversimplification, albeit applicable to the present question.

Comment: @MετάEd, sorry for posting in the incorrect place, but as in the Writers SE faqs it describes as not allowed "The strictly interpreted correctness of English grammar or syntax rules (please ask those on English Stack Exchange, instead)" I thought here would be a better place :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural version would be: *Evidence that this method is both safe and provides clinical benefits supports its recommendation.*

Note switch to singular. *Evidence* is not usually used in the plural form, except in [apologetics](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/comdesc/evidences.html).

I think, however, if you give us the surrounding paragraph, we can do even better in revising it. Evidence *always* supports something; your sentence would be stronger if it were more immediate to see just what the evidence comprises.

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer. I think that evidence in singular is perfect for my needs. In my case evidence supports that the method is safe and provides clinical benefit. It is a new clinical procedure, and as evidence supports it's safe and provides benefits (here I cite two articles), it is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The evidence *supports a finding [or conclusion]* that this method is both safe and effective . . .